# Understanding the basics of Jasper reporting with Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am just starting learning `Jasper reports` with `Java`. I searched through the web and did not find a good tutorial which teaches reporting from the very beginning. Tutorialspoint.com have a good one, but they use `ANT` for that. I can learn them after, but what I need now is to generate `jasper reports` using simple Java programs. 
I found a code from `github` which is [here](https://gist.github.com/rponte/5044469), but I have some issues with understanding that code.

```
            String reportName = "myreport";
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection(); // opens a jdbc connection

            // compiles jrxml
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(reportName + ".jrxml");
            // fills compiled report with parameters and a connection
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName + ".jasper", parameters, connection);
            // exports report to pdf
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, new FileOutputStream(reportName + ".pdf")); // your output goes here

            exporter.exportReport();
```

It generates the report using above code. But, there are some parts where I find some issues when understanding.

- Where is the Query String?
- Do I have to create the `jrxml` file separately, which contains the query string and name that file as `myreport.jrxml`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is the Query String?

In the report template (jrxml)

> Do I have to create the jrxml file separately, which contains the query string and name that file as myreport.jrxml?

Yes. You can use iReport or JasperReport Studio to create the jrxml.

Answer (score 1):

This set of tutorials is good.I learnt ireports from the begining using these videos.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM7Xsr-_8_g][1]

you can use iReport designer to create .jrxml files.Then add .jrxml file and .jasper file(which generates after compiling the report) to the project.Here's an example how you generate report in the java program.

```
public void Report(String from,String to){
        Connection conn=null;
         try {

            conn = Database.con();

            JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("src\\Reports\\report5.jrxml");
            String sql = "SELECT login.`Username` AS login_Username, login.`date` AS login_date, "
                    + "login.`task` AS login_task FROM `login` login where date(login.`date`) between '"+from+"'  and '"+to+"'";
            JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
            newQuery.setText(sql);
            jd.setQuery(newQuery);
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | JRException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this create first following getter setter

```
private JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
private JasperReport jasperReport = null;
private Map<String, Object> parameters = null;
private String applicationPath = null;
```

next create constructor

```
public JasperReportModel(String applicationPath) {
    super();
    this.applicationPath = applicationPath;
}
```

Now Write the logic to generate pdf file

```
public String generatePDFReport(Collection collection, String storageDir, String fileName) throws Exception {
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = null;
    String filePath = "";
    try {
        beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
        filePath = storageDir+File.separator+fileName+".pdf";
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, filePath);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Now write the logic for excel file

```
public String generateXLSXReport(Collection collection, String storageDir, String fileName) throws Exception {
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = null;
    String filePath = "";
    JRXlsxExporter exporter = null;
    SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = null;
    try {
        beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
        filePath = storageDir+File.separator+fileName+".pdf";
        //Create Exporter (Input / Output)
        exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(filePath)));
        //Set configuration as you like it!!
        configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
        configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
        configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
        configuration.setWhitePageBackground(true);
        configuration.setIgnorePageMargins(true);
        configuration.setMaxRowsPerSheet(65000);
        configuration.setForcePageBreaks(false);
        configuration.setWrapText(true);
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

logic to load single(main)jrxml file from java class

```
public void loadJasperReport(String templateName) throws JRException {
    File jrxmlFile = new File(applicationPath+File.separator+templateName+".jrxml");
    File jasperFile = new File(applicationPath+File.separator+"jasper"+File.separator+templateName+".jasper");
    if(jrxmlFile.exists() && !jasperFile.exists() ) {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlFile.getAbsolutePath(), jasperFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(jasperFile.getPath());        
    parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("applicationPath", applicationPath);
}
```

logic to load subreport(no:of)jrxml file from java class

```
public void loadJasperReport(String templateName, int noOfSubReport) throws JRException {
    File jrxmlSubReport = null, jasperSubReport = null;
    for(int i = 1; i <= noOfSubReport; i++) {
        jrxmlSubReport = new File(applicationPath+File.separator+templateName+"_"+i+".jrxml");
        jasperSubReport = new File(applicationPath+File.separator+"jasper"+File.separator+templateName+"_"+i+".jasper");
        if( jrxmlSubReport.exists() && !jasperSubReport.exists() ) {
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlSubReport.getAbsolutePath(), jasperSubReport.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    File jrxmlFile = new File(applicationPath+File.separator+templateName+".jrxml");
    File jasperFile = new File(applicationPath+File.separator+"jasper"+File.separator+templateName+".jasper");
    if( jrxmlFile.exists() && !jasperFile.exists() ) {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlFile.getAbsolutePath(), jasperFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(jasperFile.getPath());        
    parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("applicationPath", applicationPath+File.separator);
}
```

write action class for call the jasper module

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
```

public class ActionClass extends ActionSupport {

```
public String downloadReport(){
    String jasperFilePath="";
    JasperReportModel jasperModel = null;
    ActionSupport actionSupport = null;
    String dwnFilePath="", dwnFileName="", filePath="";
    try{
        if(isError){
            return "internalError";
        }
        DAOImpl impl= new DAOImpl();
        data = impl.getadmlistforReport("your bean class object");
        jasperFilePath = getText("pdf file path from properties file");
        jasperModel = new JasperReportModel(jasperFilePath);
        jasperModel.loadJasperReport("jrxml file name/path");
        dwnFilePath = getText("download file path from");
        String dateTimeString= new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy_hhmmss_SSS").format(new Date());
        dwnFileName = "c" + dateTimeString;
        if(report_type.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF")){
            filePath = jasperModel.generatePDFReport(data, dwnFilePath, dwnFileName);
            fileName = "report.pdf";
        }
        else if(report_type.equalsIgnoreCase("XLS")){
            filePath = jasperModel.generateXLSReport(data, dwnFilePath, dwnFileName);
            fileName = "report.xls";
        }
        else if(report_type.equalsIgnoreCase("XLSX")){
            filePath = jasperModel.generateXLSXReport(data, dwnFilePath, dwnFileName);
            fileName = "report.xlsx";
        }
        setFileInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)));
        //setFileName(new File(filePath).getName());
        System.out.println("The Download File : " + filePath);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }       
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}